# Bad performance when presenting modally over uicollectionviewcontroller on iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uicollectionview

in have a simple uicollectionviewcontroller with some simpel views in. In the UINavigationBar i have a button, when pressed presents modally (as formsheet) segue to a navigation controller, with a tableview as rootview.

On iPhone, it all works well, but on iPad the animation when it presents and when the presented tableview scroll, is bad and have low fps.

How can this be?

Please tell what kind of information from my app is needed to help me.

I am working in swift, iOS 8.3

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Okay, so i got 8 different kinds of prototypecells in my tableview, all with auto-layout in my storyboard. I have a subclass for each of them with IBOutlets.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {

                let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
                let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: NSDate())

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("weekCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WeekChooserTableViewCell
                cell.stepper.value = Double(components.weekOfYear)
                cell.weekNumber.text = String(components.weekOfYear)
                return cell
            } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomerTableViewCell
                cell.customerTextField.tag = "\(indexPath.row+1)\(indexPath.section+1)".toInt()!
                cell.customerTextField.delegate = self
                return cell
            }
        } else if indexPath.section > 0 && indexPath.section <= 5 {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("hourpayCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HourpayTableViewCell
                if arrayOfHourpay[indexPath.section-1] == 9999999999 {
                    cell.hourpayTextField.text = ""
                } else {
                    cell.hourpayTextField.text = String("\(arrayOfHourpay[indexPath.section-1])")
                }
                cell.hourpayTextField.tag = "\(indexPath.row+1)\(indexPath.section+1)".toInt()!
                cell.hourpayTextField.delegate = self
                return cell
            } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("casepayCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CasepayTableViewCell
                if arrayOfCasepay[indexPath.section-1] == 9999999999 {
                    cell.casepayTextField.text = ""
                } else {
                    cell.casepayTextField.text = String("\(arrayOfCasepay[indexPath.section-1])")
                }
                cell.casepayTextField.tag = "\(indexPath.row+1)\(indexPath.section+1)".toInt()!
                cell.casepayTextField.delegate = self
                return cell
            } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("machinepayCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MachinepayTableViewCell
                if arrayOfMachinepay[indexPath.section-1] == 9999999999 {
                    cell.machinepayTextField.text = ""
                } else {
                    cell.machinepayTextField.text = String("\(arrayOfMachinepay[indexPath.section-1])")
                }
                cell.machinepayTextField.tag = "\(indexPath.row+1)\(indexPath.section+1)".toInt()!
                cell.machinepayTextField.delegate = self
                return cell
            } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("daycommentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DayCommentTableViewCell
                cell.textView?.tag = "\(indexPath.row+1)\(indexPath.section+1)".toInt()!
                cell.textView?.text = arrayOfDayComments[indexPath.section-1]
                return cell
            }
        } else if indexPath.section == 6 {
            if indexPath.row + 1 == rowsInMaterialSection {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addMaterialCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddNewMaterialTableViewCell
                return cell
            } else {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("materialTextfieldCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MaterialTextfieldTableViewCell
                cell.MaterialTextField.text = arrayOfMaterials[indexPath.row]
                cell.MaterialTextField.tag = "\(indexPath.row+1)\(indexPath.section+1)".toInt()!
                cell.MaterialTextField.delegate = self
                return cell
            }
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("daycommentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DayCommentTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Show us your cellForRowAtIndexPath function. My guess is that you are doing something that is computationally expensive there.

Comment: Fire up the Time Profiler instrument and post a screenshot along with your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.

Comment: NSCalendar is heavy computationally. Try and pull it out of cellForRowAtIndex and just have one instance of it in memory and just call that from cellForRowAtIndex.

Comment: Thanks for your time. NSCalendar wasnt the problem. I had some badly coded shadows in my collectionview wich made the problem. Problem solved